# Yii link #comments?

Tags: hyperlink, yii

How to make link for ex: controller/action/15#comments
using CHTML::link()

how to make link without #comments, i know

Thanks

Comment: i made this by CHtml::link(
  'Link',
  array('news/item', 'id'=>$id, '#'=>'comments'),
)

Answer (score 1):

Just so the question has an answer on record:

```
CHtml::link( 'Link', array('news/item', 'id'=>$id, '#'=>'comments'));
```